# how do I make javascript print a json object (sent from ruby) without it being interpreted as html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, escaping

ruby/sinatra serving an "object.to_json" to an ajax request:

```
  ...
  content_type :json
  adam.to_json
end
#--> #<Human:0x10aa540 @x=68, @y=24, @name="Adam", @age=50>
```

js with jquery:

```
...
$("#player").html(data);
...
```

resulting in div being populated with just "#" character.

console.log(data) shows:

```
#<Human:0x10aa540 @x=68, @y=24, @name="Adam", @age=50>
```

So I'm guessing that happens because "<" and other characters are interpreted to html. How can I avoid it and show the object in a web page as it appears on debug console ?

Thanks

Comment: By escaping the appropriate characters...

Comment: isn't there a function that does exactly this for html ?

Comment: 0_o No. HTML is a **markup language**, not a programming language.

Comment: You are not understanding. I am talking about javascript. Also no need to downvote if you think a question is too easy.

Comment: @JFK: Childish is when you chide others using edits in your own answers. Let us know when you're all done with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps :

```
data.replace(/\</gi,"&lt;");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld3zR/)

Comment: you can [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The idea is to replace the character `<` by `&lt;`, where the second will be parsed as string, otherwise the browser will try to execute a script

Comment: perfect. It's literally 2 days I am using js... I am at that stage where I still don't understand what I need to understand :) Like, I just realized, since I am using jquery, there should of course be a way to do it with a single elegant jquery function.. thanks for the explaination and for the link!

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the browser to escape the HTML for you, by adding it to a temporary block and them retrieving the escaped content. This way, you ensure that all the HTML markup is escaped, not only the `>` and `<` :

```
var temp_div = document.createElement('div'); // Create temporary div

temp_div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data)); // Insert data as Text
data = temp_div.innerHTML; // Get Text escaped
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6srr/)